# Is it possible to count all with where condition in codeiginter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to do something like this

```
$this->db->count_all("grant_money")->where('id',5);
```

is it possible ?

if there is any another way to do this please let me know.Thanks

I want to do this query in single line code Like I tried above

Comment: Try `echo $this->db->where('id',5)->count_all_results('grant_money');` In one line and shorter
`

Answer (score 13):

You can use it like this.

```
$this->db->where('id',5);
$this->db->from("grant_money");
echo $this->db->count_all_results();
```

this will show all the count with where condition.

with single line try like this

```
echo $this->db->where('id',5)->from("grant_money")->count_all_results();
```

Answer (score 2):

$this->db->where('id',5)->count_all_results("grant_money");

Answer (score 1):

**Is it possible to count all with where condition in codeiginter?**

***YES***
count in CI based on condition

```
$this->db->from('mytable');
$this->db->where('field_name',"comapre_vale");
$this->db->like('filed_name',"any_value");                          
$count = $this->db->count_all_results();

echo $count;
```

An Example :

```
$this->db->from('tbl_ontime_attendance');
$this->db->where('Card_Number',$value['emp_code']);
$this->db->like('In_Time',"03/2018");

$days = $this->db->count_all_results();
echo $days;
```

this is a simple and very easy in this function i have shown the use of both the like and where clause , change according to your to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Try `get_data` function like this :

```
$count_all = $this->db->get_data("select count(1) from grant_money where id = 5");
echo $count_all;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at CodeIgniter Documentation:

Docs>Database Reference>Database Builder Class

E.g.

```
echo $this->db->count_all_results('my_table');  // Produces an integer, like 25
$this->db->like('title', 'match');
$this->db->from('my_table');
echo $this->db->count_all_results(); // Produces an integer, like 17
```

It accepts "Query Builder restrictors" such as `where()`, `or_where()`, `like()`, `or_like()`, etc.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

yes you can try this may be this will hepfull:-

```
public function record_count_with_where($table_name,$column_name,$type)
  {
    $this->db->select($column_name);
    $this->db->where($column_name,$type);
    $q=$this->db->get($table_name);
    $count=$q->result();
    return count($count);

  }
```